# REWRITE URL and keep QUERY STRING in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get, query-string

Here is my .htaccess code...

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.css$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.js$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.png$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.mp3$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.jpg$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.xml$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.txt$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.gif$
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$  /$1.php  [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com" [R=301,L]
```

I want to have: example.com/buy?r=abc123 appear like: example.com/release/abc123 or even like: example.com/abc123

I cannot $_GET the contents of r in buy.php once the url has been redirected.

I hope someone can help :)

Comment: See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa you also can list all those extensions in one rule.

Comment: I have tried...
`RewriteRule ^/example/([^/]*) /buy.php?r=$1 [L,QSA]`
&
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^buy/(.*)/$ buy.php?r=$1 [L,QSA]`
But had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want clean URLs then you can simply use:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /buy?r=$1 [L]
```

to get `example.com/abc123`

Or you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^release/([^/]*)$ /buy?r=$1 [L]
```

to get `example.com/release/abc123`.

Just make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: This code works great! however, the $1 value won't get the value from the url for some reason? 

This code results nothing...
`RewriteRule ^release/([^/]*)$ /buy?r=$1 [L]`

This code results the page as it should be displayed...
`RewriteRule ^release/([^/]*)$ /buy?r=abc123 [L]`

the code isn't picking up the value of $1 from the url for some reason?

Comment: Does `r` have multiple variables?

Comment: r changes... 

e.g. abc001, abc002, abc003 and so on

Comment: hmm, then really it should work... but then that could depend on your setup. But only you would know that, for example, it could be `r=$2`

Comment: I think this is because you cannot call the contents using `<?php echo $_GET['r'] ?>`

Comment: I have found the issue, when `RewriteRule  ^(.*)$  /$1.php  [L]` is removed from the .htaccess there is no problem. How can i get around this problem and still remove the .php extension from the url?

Comment: Have you tried simply putting the rules above everything else? Really these rules shouldn't conflict with your one to remove .php

Comment: that worked! thank you so much! Can't believe I didn't see that myself

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct :)